# Get rid of Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation, google-play-services, disable-app

I would like to freeze, or in any way disable Google Play on my Android 2.3.6.
I tried to prevent the autorun: it always finds its way.
I tried to freeze it with Gemini App Manager: even blocked it starts.

How can I definitely block or even uninstall this damned application ? Has someone succeeded in doing so ?

The reason: every time it starts, my whole phone becomes extremely slow, barely usable.

Comment: So, you don't ever want to install or update apps?

Comment: As Al said, if you do uninstall Google Play you can't download or update any apps at all. I guess you could occasionally install the store apk file and do it then uninstall. Google Play is a system app so you'd need Root and an application like Root Uninstaller (downloaded from Play Store ironically) and then uninstall system apps.

Comment: My phone is already rooted, and I already tried to block/freeze Google Play, but like I said, for Google Play it does not work, the apps unblocks itself one way or another.
I wanted to avoid uninstalling it completely to be able to sometimes use it, but maybe this is the only way. I suppose I can then use another store app to install and update my applications.

Comment: Do you have also unlocked phone? I mean unlocked bootloader, so you are able to make changes in system partition.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how well this works but if you have root you could try [this F-Droid app.](https://www.f-droid.org/en/packages/org.droidtr.deletegapps/)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward method would be to just flash a custom ROM without GApps, so you would have a clean device. Just backup all your apps with TitaniumBackup or oandbackup before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

- If your phone is rooted, then you can rename Google Apps APK file extension to ._ap_k or something like that. You can also move it outside the system/app folder. This will definitely prevent it from starting.
- You can also use startup manager and task killer apps to kill it.
- If the disable option is available in Settings -> Apps - All, then it you can disable it. Otherwise, try to disable Google Framework or Google Account. Google Apps is dependent on them.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted you can use the pm command in terminal.

Instructions:
1. Install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm
2. In the terminal emulator type "su" (without the "") and hit enter in order to obtain root permissions.
3. Then you need to type

```
pm disable package_name
```

Replace the package_name with the package name of the app you need to disable. It should work.

To enable a package do the same but replace disable with enable.

Comment: The package name of the play store should be com.android.vending